# Poucas medalhas de tag quando nos comparamos ao SOen, por que?

Tags: debate

Esses dias abri a página de medalhas e percebi que poucas medalhas de tags foram distribuídas aqui no SOpt:

### Stack Overflow em Português

[image: Medalhas SOpt]

### Stack Overflow

[image: Medalhas SOen]

Conforme [estatísticas](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) da Stack Exchange nós temos hoje em torno de **34 mil** usuários e o SOen possui em torno de **5.9 milhões**.

Fazendo uma conta de padeiro para descobrir qual o percentual de usuários que receberam medalhas (é de padeiro pois um usuário pode ter várias medalhas, então o percentual real é menor do que esse. Provavelmente alguém mais nerd do que eu consegue obter as estatísticas no sistema):

- **SOpt**: 301 / 34000 = 0.00885. **~0.885%**
- **SOen**: 96100 / 5900000 = 0.01628. **~1.628%**

Ou seja, no SOen um percentual consideravelmente maior de usuários obteve alguma medalha.

Por que vocês acham que isso acontece? Ainda é uma questão de massa crítica / idade do site? Falta engajamento de alguma maneira? Lusófonos são mais difíceis de impressionar?

Comment: Acho que é mesmo problema da idade do site, já viste a quantidade de utilizadores com mais de 10k de reputação?

Comment: Corrigido, thanks. Pois é, acredito que acaba sendo uma questão de banco de reputação mesmo. Estou curioso para saber se daqui a alguns anos essas estatísticas vão estar mais próximas uma da outra.

Comment: Sem querer polemizar eu **acho** que é o que eu disse outras vezes, faltam especialistas. Eu queria ver bem mais pessoas respondendo, ter bem mais respostas por pergunta, mesmo que só para complementar. Também acho que faltam votos (claro que lá é mais fácil atingir o mínimo, aqui deveria ter *target* menor?). O SOen tem muito isso desde sua infância, depois caiu (pelo menos é minha percepção). Tenho a impressão que aqui teve muito cedo muita pergunta do tipo *helpdesk* que as respostas costumam ter poucos votos. Claro que estatísticas sempre mostram um quadro específico,ñ a mais pura verdade.

Comment: 2012 e 2013 foram anos bem fortes para o SOen, foi meio que uma febre e os usuários em porcentagem são bem mais participativos no SOen. Todavia lá tem uma coisa que detesto, o imenso numero de perguntas repetitivas e mal feitas, que as vezes até ganham upvotes, em quanto as perguntas mais ineditas e uteis ficam as moscas (varia muito conforme o horário). Acho que vai muito das pessoas que "votam".

Comment: Não olhei números, ainda, mas acredito que o @JorgeB. tem razão sobre o impacto da idade do site no número de medalhas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu as perguntas que lá fiz eram todas inéditas e bem pensadas, mas sobre assuntos que ninguém quer saber, então nem repostas tive muitas vezes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento infelizmente isto não é só exclusividade do SOEn, ocorre aqui com bastante frequência também.

Comment: @bigown, de antemão, não estou gerando polêmica, mas o que define *especialistas*? Seriam mais 'respondedores' ou respostas técnicas e detalhadas? É só para ajudar a compreender a carência do SOPT.

Comment: Não sei qual o perfil gringo, nem de PT, mas no Brasil muita gente migrou de fóruns onde a procura é algo que resolva um problema e ignora-se as explicações. Temos inúmeras questões com respostas satisfatórias e nota-se que o AP deu-se por satisfeito, abandona a questão sem voto.

Comment: @PapaCharlie um pouco de cada :) Claro que falta respondedores. Mas falta respondedores em especial que saibam responder bem. Não precisa ser respostas maravilhosas, mas tem gente que responde coisas sem sentido, muito no chute, que não sabem fazer mas dão pitaco,aí reclamam de tomar negativo de receber reclamações. Obviamente estes tem baixa reputação e costumam contribuir pouco, até porque acabam achando que o site é chato, eles querem receber reconhecimento por algo que eles não sabem. É uma pena, mas é uma realidade. Então precisa ter os dois, + gente respondendo, e + que respondem bem.

Comment: @bigown faltam também bons perguntadores, existem muitas perguntas que são respondidas no SOpt e que o usuário não retorna para a questão para avaliar as respostas, existem muitas perguntas com várias respostas, onde o usuário não aceita nenhuma delas e também não fecha a questão.

Comment: @JulioBorges concordo. Embora aí seja uma questão de tamanho. Proporcional acredito que hoje está mais ou menos igual ao SOen. Mas lá tem 100 vezes mais, ajuda um pouco tirar qualidade absoluta disso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É complicado modelar esse problema em uma só estatística, pelo menos sem um PhD e estatística, pra conseguir comparar realmente nosso desempenho com o do SOen. A variação no número de pessoas, número de tags, quantidade de posts por usuário, quantidade de tags por post é gigantesca demais pra conseguir fazer qualquer modelagem que não deixe à desejar.

Dito isso, vou fazer a minha conta de guardanapo em mesa de bar.

Como disse no [meu comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5280/poucas-medalhas-de-tag-quando-nos-comparamos-ao-soen-por-que#comment19290_5280), concordando com a [análise do @JorgeB](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5280/poucas-medalhas-de-tag-quando-nos-comparamos-ao-soen-por-que#comment19286_5280), medalhas de tag requerem tempo. Quase metade dos votos ocorrem mais de uma semana depois da criação do post. Mais de 20% acontece mais de *1 mês* depois. A distância média entre a criação do post e o voto é de **58 dias**.

Hoje mesmo nós tivemos 2 votos feitos 992 dias depois do post. E 992 dias é justamente a idade do nosso site. Todo dia há um novo recorde de "tempo passado entre o post e o voto".

Então decidi dar uma olhada na distância média entre a criação da conta e o recebimento de uma medalha de tag de bronze no SOen. O resultado foi **1087 dias**. Como eu disse ali em cima, nosso site só tem 992 dias de vida até agora.

Considerando que média básica não é uma boa medida pra casos assim, já que quanto mais velho o site, maior o desvio padrão (por causa do acúmulo de distâncias cada vez maiores entre criação da conta e recebimento da medalha), fui dar uma olhada na distribuição:

[image: Dias entre criação da conta e a medalha de tag de bronze]

À pedido do @AnthonyAccioly, também vi a distribuição do tempo entre o *primeiro post* e o recebimento de uma medalha de tag de bronze:

[image: Dias entre o primeiro post e a medalha de tag de bronze]

Há claramente, em ambos os casos, um acúmulo em torno dos 1000 dias de presença no site. É nesse intervalo que estão a maioria das medalhas de tag ganhas.
<sup>Lembrando que isso **não quer dizer que a maioria das medalhas ocoreu dentro dos primeiros 1000 dias do site**</sup>

Como eu disse, essa análise não é perfeita, nem precisa, nem explica a situação inteira. Mas acredito que mostra bem o impacto do tempo sobre a distribuição das medalhas de tag.

---

O @VictorStafusa [pediu](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5280/poucas-medalhas-de-tag-quando-nos-comparamos-ao-soen-por-que/5324?noredirect=1#comment19630_5324) pra ver a comparação entre medalhas de bronze, prata e ouro no SOen. Tá aqui, mas agora agrupado por **meses**, pra ficar mais fácil de ver:

[image: Tempo, em meses, entre primeira pergunta e recebimento da medalha, para as 3 classes de medalha]

Comment: Oi Gabe, muito bacana. Para chegar nesse período médio de praticamente 3 anos você está olhando somente para medalhas de bronze ou para medalhas em geral? Tem como obter uma medida de tempo considerando o dia da primeira resposta de um usuário como ponto de partida?

Comment: De qualquer maneira, olhando para sua distribuição e os percentuais (de padeiro) da pergunta parece que o comportamento dos dois sites está razoavelmente próximo sim. No SOEN esse efeito cumulativo é visível e parece que um percentual significativo (~ metade?) das medalhas demoraram mais de 1000 dias para serem entregues. Isso reforça a hipótese de idade / massa crítica.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly É, como eu disse, a análise é bem simplória e não representa uma explicação completa das diferenças e tal. Só queria mesmo ver se "tempo" é algo que tem impacto, e claramente tem. Vou dar uma olhada na query que você pediu

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Pronto. Esclareci que os dados são sobre medalhas de bronze, e adicionei o gráfico para tempo entre o primeiro post e uma medalha... Não há tanta diferença assim.

Comment: Dá para fazer a mesma medida com as medalhas de prata e de ouro? Só para saber se seguem algum padrão semelhante às de bronze, mas em um período maior.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Tá lá

Answer (score -2):

Essa é uma captura de tela do anúncio oficial de lançamento oficial do SO matriz:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E essa é uma captura de tela do anúncio oficial do lançamento do SO lusófono:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado :)

P.s.: dê tempo ao tempo.

Comment: Acho que não ajudou. A questão é tão mais complexa que isso...

Comment: O SO só foi lançado em 2008? Tinha ideia que era mais antigo...